# Default initialization of C++ member array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, struct, constructor

Suppose I have a C++ class set up as follows:

```
class Foo{
  public:
    struct Pair{
      int x;
      int y;
      Pair(){ x = 2; y = 4; }
    };

  private:
    Pair pairArr[16];
}
```

Without otherwise initializing the pairArr, what is the default value of the Pair structs inside it? Does C++ call the constructor (initializing it with x=2, y=4) or are the objects not created yet, leaving me with an array of "junk" objects until I initialize the indices myself?

I know if it is an array of a primitive data type, they are default initialized (if I had an array of ints, they would all be 0). However, I don't know if this behavior holds for more complex objects like my struct here.

Comment: You really should learn to use the *initializer list* in your constructors. Here it makes no big difference, but it *can* have a real performance implication compared to using the ctor body (depending on the member types).

Comment: "I know if it is an array of an atomic type, they are default initialized" - you know wrong - where are you learning this stuff from? Also, where did you pick up the notion of "atomic type"?

Comment: The objects of your array will be *default initialized*. Since your class is not an aggregate type (because of a user-defined constructor), your default constructor will be called to *construct* each of the element in the array

Comment: @JesperJuhl That, and member references (as well as any type that's non-copyable and non-moveable) can *only* be initialized using the initializer list, so in some cases it's not even about performance -- it's the only option at all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes and structs are equivalent in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it's only the default *access specifier* that differs. So check [Arrays and Classes](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/cop3330/notes/arrayobj.html), which says:

> The normal array declaration style uses the default constructor for each object in the array (if the class has a default constructor)

---

From a practical point of view, do this in your struct:

```
Pair() : x(2), y(4) { std::cout << "Called\n"; }
```

and you will see the message being printed 16 times.

That's a usual approach (to add print messages to constructor to destructor) when you want to know what is called (and usually their order).

---

Tip: Use an initializer list, rather than assigning values inside the body of the constructor.

Comment: You should recommend using member initialization instead of assignment in ctor body.